# Poor performance with Tabbar

Tags: performance, tabbar

Tabbar is refreshing groups like 14+ times at once (probably number of tabs) and causing severe slowness with the mods I made on it (lots of IO to sort tabs in mod time). What is the preferred way to debounce or throttle function calls in elisp?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in solutions for that, but you could probably implement something with [timers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html). FWIW, Emacs 27 comes with a couple of built-in tab modes.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a performance *bug*.  Please report it as such before you settle on circumventing it.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Do you see this if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, consider reporting a bug. But you say *"with the mods I made on it (lots of IO to sort tabs in mod time)"*, which makes it sound like the problem might be with some code you have, not with vanilla Emacs. And you don't show any code...

Comment: The function `force-mode-line-update` with the optional argument `t` forces the header-line (with the old-school `tabbar.el` library) to refresh on every window of every frame.  If, for example, the header-line is forced to update unnecessarily, this will cause a slow-down.  I would suggest using the performance profiling and see if anything stands out:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html  Note that there is a new tabbar built-in to developmental versions of Emacs, and your question does not specify whether you are talking about a Lisp version `tabbar.el`.

Comment: @lawlist profiler shows tabbar eating more than 50% of processing, but it's because I changed it to sort buffers by modification time. The mix didn't go well. Tabbar refreshes the line 3 times each character is typed and I added a file system call to sort by modtime to make everything slower... I should've asked just for a throttle function. It's not a bug really.